# Is it possible to save the child object by Just updating the parent object in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose in my Nodejs application to save two schemas are:

**Needs Object:**

```
let needSchema = new Schema({
dateCreated : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
detail : String,
quantity : Number,
delivered : Number
});
```

**OrphanageHome Object**

```
let orphanageHomeSchema = new Schema({    
    dateCreated : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    detail : String,
    name: String,
    address: String,
    mobile:Number,
    email: String,
    noOfChildren: Number,
    needs : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'need'}],
    location: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point'],
            required: true
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

**anytime I try to update an existing orphangehome object with a new need object, it fails to save the need object and tie it to the orphangehome object.** why is this ?

```
    newNeed = {
    _id : "random",
    detail : 'random',
    quantity : 'random',
    delivered : 'random'

    } 

 existingOrphanageHome.needs.push[newNeed];

orphanageODM.findByIdAndUpdate(existingOrphanageHome._id, existingOrphanageHome, function (err, 
updatedOrphanageHome) {

        callback(err, updatedOrphanageHome);

    });
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the `findByIdAndUpdate` callback?

Comment: @Royson ....... No.  I get a populated 'updatedOrphanageHome' meaning that it went through. But when I check the DB, I discover no need is saved.